# UITableView strange issue

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with around 10 cells, placed in a view controller in the middle of a program. When I run the program, the table view shows. But if I start quickly selecting random `UITableViewCells`, the program crashes. I don't know how this is possible because I can do it in another application with a `UITableView` and nothing interesting happens. How????

EDIT: Nevermind. I fixed it by removing some unnecessary statements.

Comment: we will need to know the crash and some code (minimally the table handling code/what you do when a cell is clicked)

Answer (score 0):

Check with your coding.May be you have done some silly mistake at the time assigning text to the cells are some where else. Look into your coding.

For your reference you can refer this link.

http://iphonesdevsdk.blogspot.com/2011/04/uitableview.html